# Simplify $\mathbb{E}\left[ -\log \left( \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{z-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^{2}} \right) \right]$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value, gaussian

How to simplify the following expected value?

\begin{align}
&= \mathbb{E}[ -\log f(x)] \\ 
&= \mathbb{E}\left[ -\log \left( \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{z-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^{2}} \right) \right]\\
&= ?
\end{align}

Is the next step

$$\mathbb{E}\left[ -\log\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}- \left( -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{z-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^{2} \right) \right] ?$$
and from there, how to reduce further to non-expectation form?

Comment: calculate an intergal: $\int\limits_{- \infty}^{+\infty} - e^{-\frac{(z - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}} \cdot \log \left( \frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}} \cdot e^{-\frac{(z - \mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}} \right)$

Comment: isn't the whole point of this expectations representation ($\mathbb{E}$) is to avoid trying to derive from integrals? The expectations route should be a cleaner way to arrive at a closed-form solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Joitandr's approach is overkill, given what you've already done. By the linearity of expectation, the result is $\log(\sigma\sqrt{2\pi})+\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\underbrace{\Bbb E[(z-\mu)^2]}_{\sigma^2}=\log(\sigma\sqrt{2e\pi})$.

Comment: was my attempted third line correct? and how does it connect to where you started?

Comment: @develarist I just continued from your last line.

Comment: could you show how $\mathbb{E}\left[ -\log\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}- \left( -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{z-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^{2} \right) \right] =  \log(\sigma\sqrt{2\pi})+\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\underbrace{\Bbb E[(z-\mu)^2]}_{\sigma^2}$?

Comment: @develarist Don't you know that $\log (Ae^{B})=\log A+B$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy of course, I even use the rule in the question itself. My question to him is not about that rule

Comment: How about $\log \frac 1 x=-\log x$? @develarist

Comment: thanks @KaviRamaMurthy, forgot that one somehow its early

Comment: @develarist I combined $-\ln\tfrac1x=\ln x$ with $\Bbb E[A+BX]=A+B\Bbb E[X]$ for constants $A,\,B$.

Comment: how does $\log(\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}) + \frac{1}{2} = \log(\sigma\sqrt{2e\pi})$? the half looks like it suddenly becomes an exponential under the square root

Comment: @develarist $\tfrac12=\log\sqrt{e}$; now use $\log A+\log B=\log AB$ and $A\sqrt{B}\sqrt{C}=A\sqrt{BC}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy if $\log \frac 1 x=-\log x$, is it also true that $-\log \frac 1 x=\log x$?